# How can I type this function without resorting to 'any'

Tags: typescript

I have this function that takes an object and two strings and returns an array of typed objects using the strings to pick two properties from the supplied objects.

My compiler warns *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.* for the two lines inside the map function.

```js
export interface SelectOption {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

/**
 * Map an array of objects to an array of objects compatible with select drop downs
 * specifying the keys to be used for the value and the label
 * @param items the object to map from
 * @param valueField The field in the object containing the value
 * @param labelField The field in the object containing the label
 */
export const mapObjectsToSelectOptions = (
  items: object[],
  valueField: string,
  labelField: string,
): SelectOption[] => {
  return items
    .map(o => ({
      value: o[valueField],
      label: o[labelField],
    }));
};
```

Is there any way around this in Typescript? I have tried creating a type for the items parameter like this:

```js
interface ObjectBase {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

But of course the supplied object may not have such a type, and so I get an error when calling the function. Could I use a generic somehow?

Comment: Try using the `keyof` type: `valueField: keyof ItemTypeHere`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `mapObjectsToSelectOptions` generic, with 3 type parameters: one for the exact object type `T`, and two others for two fields names: for value and for label, named `VF` and `LF`. Then the compiler can infer  value type as `T[VF]`, and label type as `T[LF]`:

```
export const mapObjectsToSelectOptions = 
<T extends object, VF extends keyof T, LF extends keyof T>(
  items: T[],
  valueField: VF,
  labelField: LF,
) => { // the inferred return type is OK: {value: T[VF], label: T[LF]}[]
  return items
    .map(o => ({
      value: o[valueField],
      label: o[labelField],
    }));
};

const testObject1 = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'B',
    c: 'Q'
}

const testObject2 = {
    a: 5,
    b: 'B',
    e: 'E'
}

const selectOptions = mapObjectsToSelectOptions([testObject1, testObject2], 'a', 'b');
// returned type is
// const selectOptions: {
//     value: number;
//     label: string;
// }[]

const selectOptions2 = mapObjectsToSelectOptions([testObject1, testObject2], 'a', 'c'); 
// error, not all objects have 'c'
```